# Prolog converting integer to a list of digit

Tags: list, prolog, digit, clpfd

I want to write a predicate that an integer and a list of digits, and succeed if Digits contain the digits of the integer in the proper order, i.e:

```
?-digit_lists( Num, [1,2,3,4] ).
[Num == 1234].
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
my_digits( 0, [] ).
my_digits(N,[A|As]) :- N1 is floor(N/10), A is N mod 10, my_digits(N1, As).
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It's not good form to ask for help with your homework without attempting anything.

Comment: Try reversing the list before calling my_digits/2, because then your logic will apply...

Answer (score 5):

I think this is easier:

```
numToList(NUM,[LIST|[]]):-
   NUM < 10,
   LIST is NUM,
   !.
numToList(NUM,LIST):-
   P is NUM // 10,
   numToList(P,LIST1),
   END is (NUM mod 10), 
   append(LIST1,[END] ,LIST).
```

Comment: Although I'm a fan of the simplicity of this approach, it should be noted it unfortunately does not work both ways (giving it a list will not build the number), which is something that we should strive for in Prolog,

Answer (score 4):

As already suggested, consider using finite domain constraints:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

number_digits(Number, 0, [Number]) :- Number in 0..9.
number_digits(Number, N, [Digit|Digits]) :-
        Digit in 0..9,
        N #= N1 + 1,
        Number #= Digit*10^N + Number1,
        Number1 #>= 0,
        N #> 0,
        number_digits(Number1, N1, Digits).
```

This predicate can be used in all directions. Examples with either argument instantiated:

```
?- number_digits(215, _, Ds).
Ds = [2, 1, 5] ;
false.

?- number_digits(N, _, [4,3,2,1]).
N = 4321 ;
false.
```

And two more general queries:

```
?- number_digits(N, _, [A,B]).
N in 10..99,
_G2018+B#=N,
_G2018 in 10..90,
A*10#=_G2018,
A in 0..9,
B in 0..9 ;
false.

?- number_digits(N, _, Ds).
Ds = [N],
N in 0..9 ;
Ds = [_G843, _G846],
N in 0..99,
_G870+_G846#=N,
_G870 in 0..90,
_G843*10#=_G870,
_G843 in 0..9,
_G846 in 0..9 ;
etc.
```

Comment: Is `Digit in 1..9` a typo?  I was expecting `Digit in 0..9` instead.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here comes yet another variant based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)... Based on `(#=)/3` and [`if_//3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367581/4609915) we define:

```
n_base_digits(N, R, Ds) :-
   N #> 0,                                  % positive integers only
   R #> 1,                                  % smallest base = 2
   Ds = [D|_],                              % leading digit may not be 0
   D #> 0,
   phrase(n_base_digits_aux(N, R, Ds), Ds).

n_base_digits_aux(N, Base, [_|Rs]) -->
   { D #= N mod Base,
     M #= N // Base },
   if_(M #= 0,
       { Rs = [] },
       n_base_digits_aux(M, Base, Rs)),
   [D].
```

Query using SICStus Prolog 4.3.3:

```
| ?- n_base_digits(1234, 10, Ds).
Ds = [1,2,3,4] ? ;
no
```

Works the other way round, too!

```
| ?- n_base_digits(I,10,[1,2,3]).
I = 123 ? ;
no
```

Note that the above is  faster than `number_digits/3` as proposed [by @mat in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16067299/4609915).

Answer (score 1):

You could also avoid recursion and use in-built predicates for type conversions:

```
my_digits(Number, List) :-
    atomic_list_concat(List, Atom),
    atom_number(Atom, Number).
```

The first line converts the list to an atom, and the second line converts this atom to a number, which will give true if that number is the same as that passed in.

I don't know if there is an even more direct way to convert the list into a number (don't think so..), in which case it could be achieved in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with @ssBarBee. After all, you should get 4321 if you supply your list and their allegation is correct; but instead you get this:

```
?- my_digits(Num, [1,2,3,4]).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

We could try it with `clpfd`:

```
my_digits( 0, [] ).
my_digits(N,[A|As]) :- N1 #= N/10, A #= N mod 10, my_digits(N1, As).
```

We get this:

```
?- my_digits(Num, [1,2,3,4]), label([Num]).
Num = -6789 ;
Num = 4321.
```

I find all that pretty curious, but tracing with clpfd is not pleasant.

If you just wanted to parse a list of numbers I would be inclined to make it tail recursive like so:

```
my_digits(Num, List) :- my_digits(0, List, Num).

my_digits(Num, [], Num).
my_digits(N, [A|As], Num) :- N1 is N * 10 + A, my_digits(N1, As, Num).
```

This gives us:

```
?- my_digits(Num, [1,2,3,4]).
Num = 1234 ;
false.
```

But it doesn't generate:

```
?- my_digits(1234, X).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

If I were solving this without clpfd, I'd be inclined at this point to just inspect my arguments and have separate predicates. Gross, I know, but that's what I'd do.

```
my_digits(Num, List) :- 
    nonvar(List), 
    my_digits_p(0, List, Num).
my_digits(Num, List) :- 
    var(List), 
    my_digits_g(Num, ListRev), 
    reverse(ListRev, List).

my_digits_p(Num, [], Num).
my_digits_p(N, [A|As], Num) :- N1 is N * 10 + A, my_digits(N1, As, Num).

my_digits_g(0, []) :- !.
my_digits_g(N, [A|As]) :- A is N mod 10, N1 is floor(N / 10), my_digits_g(N1, As).
```

This can parse or check, or generate if the number is a non-variable:

```
?- my_digits(1234, X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4].

?- my_digits(X, [1,2,3,4]).
X = 1234 ;
false.

?- my_digits(1234, [1,2,3,4]).
true;
false.
```

If you try and generate with both arguments as variables you'll get a pretty unhelpful result though:

```
?- my_digits(X, Y).
X = 0,
Y = [].
```

So we can try and generate by adding another special case to my_digits:

```
my_digits(Num, List) :- 
    var(Num), var(List), 
    my_digits_g_from(0, Num, ListRev), 
    reverse(ListRev, List).
my_digits(Num, List) :- 
    nonvar(List), 
    my_digits_p(0, List, Num).
my_digits(Num, List) :- 
    var(List), 
    my_digits_g(Num, ListRev),
    reverse(ListRev, List).

my_digits_g_from(N, N, List)   :- my_digits_g(N, List).
my_digits_g_from(N, Num, List) :- succ(N, N1), my_digits_g_from(N1, Num, List).
```

That's a lot of code, and a good demonstration of the kind of acrobatics one has to do when not using `clp(fd)`. It's an unfortunate fact that when doing arithmetic in Prolog one must work around the fact that `is` does not unify, but the complexity of `clp(fd)` is good proof of why that is.

I hope someone else has a more elegant solution!

Comment: I agree Daniel. I rushed with a comment, which lead to an inaccurate one. +1 for the work and time you've invested into the code above.

Comment: It happens to us all. Thanks!

Comment: This yields an instantiation error for example on the query `?- my_digits(N, [_]).`

Comment: Yes, it's not perfect. Like I mentioned, this is more of a demonstration of how hard it is to deal with arithmetic outside of `clp(fd)`. If you see an easy way to fix that I'd like to know it.

Comment: Easy: Check out the clp(fd) version I posted. Why do it with low-level arithmetic if it feels gross even to yourself? You conveyed the impression that your final version is a finished alternative, I only wanted to point out explicitly that despite  your efforts (which I admire), it *still* is not.

Answer (score 0):

For a class assignment? What the professor is probably looking for is something like the following. A a general rule, your analysis of the problem statement should first identify the special cases (in this case, zero and negative values) and then the general case.

```
: -- int_2_digits/2 ------------------------------------------------------------
: 
: The public api.
:
: we've got 2 special cases here:
: 
: * zero, and
: * negative numbers
:
: and, of course, the general case: a positive value.
:
: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int_2_digits( 0 , [0] ) .       : zero is a special case
int_2 digits( X , ['-'|Ds] ) :- : negative numbers are a special case
  X < 0 ,                       :   which we handle (YMMV) by prepending the
  X1 is - X ,                   :   sign and than processing the absolute value
  int_2_digits(X1,Ds) .         :
int_2_digits( X , Ds       ) :- : the general case is a positive value
  X > 0 ,                       : just invoke the worker predicate.
  int_2_digits(X,[],Ds) .       :

: -- int_2_digits/3 ------------------------------------------------------------
: 
: The guts of the operation.
: 
: We're using an accumulator here because we compute the result right-to-left,
: from least significant digit to most significant digit. Using the accumulator
: builds the list in the correst sequence, so we don't have to reverse it at
: the end.
: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int_2_digits( 0 , Ds , Ds ) .      : if we hit zero, we're done. Unify the accumulator with the result
int_2_digits( X , Ts  , Ds ) :-    : otherwise...
  D is mod(X,10) ,                 : - get the current digit (X modulo 10)
  T is div(X,10) ,                 : - get the next value via integer division
  int_2_digits( X1 , [T|Ts] , Ds ) : - recurse down
  .                                : Easy!
```