# Eliminate consecutive duplicates

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif, logical-purity

Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements.

My solution for this is:

```
compress([X,X|Xs], Q) :-
   compress([X|Xs], Q).
compress([X,Y|Xs], Q) :-
   X \= Y,
   compress([Y|Xs], QR),
   append([X], QR, Q).
compress([X|[]], Q) :-
   compress([], QR),
   append([X], QR, Q).
compress([], []).
```

And, because of the fact I am beginner and I have no experience in a logic paradigm I ask you for say what I can improve and why my solution is not good as it can be.

For example, `X \= Y` doesn't look pretty to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We start with the **name** of the predicate.

Why do you use an *imperative* to denote a **relation**? A good Prolog program is usable in *all directions*, whereas an imperative always suggests a particular direction or mode of use. Therefore, choose a **declarative name** and aim for generality and [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).

Next, what about the most general query:

```
?- compress(Ls, Cs).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

Not very nice! We expect this to yield at least a few answers.

What if we use iterative deepening:

```
?- length(Ls, _), compress(Ls, Cs).
Ls = Cs, Cs = [] ;
Ls = Cs, Cs = [_G841] ;
Ls = [_G841, _G841],
Cs = [_G841] ;
Ls = [_G841, _G841, _G841],
Cs = [_G841] .
```

Hm! Quite a few answers are missing! What about the case where the elements are **different**? As you already intuitively expect, it is the use of impure predicates that leads to such effects.

Therefore, use **[prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)**, i.e., `dif/2`, to denote that two terms are *different*. It's usable in all directions!

Moreover, DCGs (**[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)**) are often useful when describing lists.

So, in total, what about this:

```
compression([])     --> [].
compression([L|Ls]) --> [L], compression_(Ls, L).

compression_([], _) --> [].
compression_([X|Xs], L) -->
        (   { X = L },
            compression_(Xs, L)
        ;   { dif(X, L) },
            [X],
            compression_(Xs, X)
        ).
```

We use the interface predicate `phrase/2` to work with the DCG.

Usage examples:

```
?- phrase(compression(Ls), Cs).
Ls = Cs, Cs = [] ;
Ls = Cs, Cs = [_G815] ;
Ls = [_G815, _G815],
Cs = [_G815] .

?- length(Ls, _), phrase(compression(Ls), Cs).
Ls = Cs, Cs = [] ;
Ls = Cs, Cs = [_G865] ;
Ls = [_G865, _G865],
Cs = [_G865] ;
Ls = Cs, Cs = [_G1111, _G1114],
dif(_G1114, _G1111) .
```

Take it from here! Improve determinism, find an even better name etc.

Comment: You messed up in my head! But it is a very good information becasue it means a progress! :) . Let's try to understand:

"Therefore, use prolog-dif, i.e., dif/2, to denote that two terms are different. It's usable in all directions!"
I don't understand why I should `dif/2 ` instead of `\=` ? Especially, you highlight *directions*. What do you mean exactly because I can't get it.

Comment: `"length(Ls, _), compress(Ls, Cs).
Ls = Cs, Cs = [] ;
Ls = Cs, Cs = [_G841] ;
Ls = [_G841, _G841],
Cs = [_G841] ;
Ls = [_G841, _G841, _G841],
Cs = [_G841] ."`. What did you want to show me in that code? :)

Comment: "Not very nice! We expect this to yield at least a few answers."
Ideed, you right. But what is an expected behaviour here? After all, in `compress(Ls, Cs)` `Ls` is not a list so it should be something like undefined  behaviour ( yes, I am programming in C++ ;) )

Comment: We are defining *relations*, and we expect to be able to use them in all modes: All arguments instantiated: Check them. No argument instantiated: Generate some solutions or answers. Arguments partially instantiated: Fill in missing details. Your initial predicate falls short in one or more of these aspects: It loops, omits answers, succeeds wrongly etc. Try it in different usage modes, not only if one list is fully instantiated! Try variables, partially instantiated lists and so on.

Comment: Ok, now I grasped what you meant. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Building on [the answer by @mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376308/4609915) (+1), why not *improve determinacy* for cases like this one:

```
?- phrase(compression([a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d]), Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c, d] ;
false.
```

With **`; false`** the SWI [prolog-toplevel](/questions/tagged/prolog-toplevel) indicates that the goal did not succeed deterministically.

We can improve `compression_//2` by using [`if_//3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367581/4609915)—the [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) analogue of [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c/27358600):

```
compression_([], _) --> [].
compression_([X|Xs], L) -->
   if_(X = L,                           % is this item equal to previous one?
       compression_(Xs, L),             %   yes: old "run" goes on
       ([X], compression_(Xs, X))).     %    no: new "run" starts
```

Sample query:

```
?- phrase(compression([a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d]), Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c, d].                            % succeeds deterministically
```