# Include non-unique elements only

Tags: list, prolog

This question was asked but there are no answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41963883/7473772). I read the comments and tried  to implement in both ways, but there are more problems that I don't understand.

I first tried the easy way that doesn't keep original order:

```
list_repeated(L, Ds) :-
    msort(L, S),
    sorted_repeated(S, Ds).

sorted_repeated([], []).
sorted_repeated([X|Xs], Ds) :-
    first(Xs, X, Ds).

first([], _, []).
first([X|Xs], X, [X|Ds]) :-
    more(Xs, X, Ds).
first([X|Xs], Y, Ds) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    first(Xs, X, Ds).

more([], _, []).
more([X|Xs], X, Ds) :-
    more(Xs, X, Ds).
more([X|Xs], Y, Ds) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    first(Xs, X, Ds).
```

Once the list is sorted without removing duplicates, using `first` and `more` I add the element to the second argument if it occurs at least twice and skip all consecutive copies of the element.

This is not working properly because if I have:

```
?- list_duplicates([b,a,a,a,b,b], Ds).
```

I get answer `[a,b]` instead of `[b,a]` and also I get `; false` after the answer.

I also tried another way, but this doesn't work because the accumulator is immutable?

```
list_duplicates(L, Ds) :-
    ld_acc(L, [], Ds).

ld_acc([], _, []).
ld_acc([X|Xs], Acc, Ds) :-
    (   memberchk(X, Acc)
    ->  Ds = [X|Ds0],
        ld_acc(Xs, Acc, Ds0)
    ;   Acc1 = [X|Acc],
        ld_acc(Xs, Acc1, Ds)
    ).
```

This cannot work because when I check that an element is member of accumulator I remove only one occurrence of each element: if I have three times the same element in the first argument, I am left with two. If I could change the element in the accumulator then I could maybe put a counter on it? In the first version I used different states, `first` and `more`, but here I have to attach state to the elements of the accumulator, is that possible?

Comment: Wait... you get `[a,b]` instead of `[a,b]`? Not sure I follow. The `; false` means Prolog first succeeded with an answer `[a,b]`, then you typed `;` (or space) asking Prolog to find additional solutions. It found no additional solutions, so it said `false`.

Comment: Can you explain what `first(..)` and `more(..)`, etc. are doing. Furthermore all variables in Prolog are basically *immutable*. The only thing that can happen is that they are further *grounded*.

Comment: Hello @lurker, I get `[a,b]` instead of `[b,a]`. Someone already corrected my question. I think it is my error that Prolog is asking for additional solutions when I think that there are no additional solutions.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The question title is probably not good. It says "include duplicates" but it means "second argument is a list of unique elements that occur more than once in the first argument". I think some of the answers are also confused but I am not sure.

Comment: @User9213: not that I want to insult you or anything. But perhaps in the (near) future you better reread your question before posting. If you include (complex) code fragments describe briefly what the functions are supposed to do. *please* :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I reread the question and there were some mistakes left after that. I thought it was clear from the question what the code has to do, but I was wrong about this, too. It is not easy to explain with words what code does because I am not very good at writing English.

Comment: @User9213: No, I understand :) don't worry. But well formatted questions tend to be answered faster and with answers that are more to the point so you will benefit from it as well :)

Comment: @User9213: Such changes as you now did, are better added separately. You are invalidating the existing answers.

Comment: @false I see but the original question contained code that solved the problem as it was meant, not as it was understood, correctly already. So to not invalidate the answers I would have to remove the whole first code example completely.

Comment: I don't think that the question as originally worded was too bad, FWIW. My answer meets the new requirements just as well as the old, even if it is not a textbook on DCGs :P

Answer (score 2):

## A plea for purity

When programming in Prolog, a major attraction is the **generality** we enjoy from pure **relations**.

This lets us use our code in **multiple directions**, and reason *declaratively* over our programs and answers.

You can enjoy these benefits if you keep your programs **pure**.

## Possible solution

As always when describing *lists*, also consider using **DCG notation**. See [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) for more information.

For example, to **describe** the *list* of duplicates in a pure way, consider:

```
list_duplicates([]) --> [].
list_duplicates([L|Ls]) -->
        list_duplicates_(Ls, L),
        list_duplicates(Ls).

list_duplicates_([], _) --> [].
list_duplicates_([L0|Ls], L) -->
        if_(L0=L, [L], []),
        list_duplicates_(Ls, L).
```

This uses [**`if_//3`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367581/1613573) to retain **generality** *and* **determinism** (if applicable).

## Examples

Here are a few example queries and answers. We start with simple **ground** cases:

```
?- phrase(list_duplicates([a,b,c]), Ds).
Ds = [].

?- phrase(list_duplicates([a,b,a]), Ds).
Ds = [a].
```

Even the most impure version will be able to handle these situations correctly. So, slightly more interesting:

```
?- phrase(list_duplicates([a,b,X]), Ds).
X = a,
Ds = [a] ;
X = b,
Ds = [b] ;
Ds = [],
dif(X, b),
dif(X, a).
```

Pretty nice, isn't it? The last part says: `Ds = []` is a solution *if* `X` is **different** from `b` and `a`. Note the pure relation `dif/2` automatically appears in these residual goals and retains the relation's generality.

Here is an example with *two* variables:

```
?- phrase(list_duplicates([X,Y]), Ds).
X = Y,
Ds = [Y] ;
Ds = [],
dif(Y, X).
```

Finally, consider using **iterative deepening** to fairly *enumerate* answers for lists of *arbitrary length*:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(list_duplicates(Ls), Ds).
Ls = Ds, Ds = [] ;
Ls = [_136],
Ds = [] ;
Ls = [_136, _136],
Ds = [_136] ;
Ls = [_156, _162],
Ds = [],
dif(_162, _156) ;
Ls = Ds, Ds = [_42, _42, _42] ;
Ls = [_174, _174, _186],
Ds = [_174],
dif(_186, _174) .
```

## Multiple occurrences

Here is a version that handles **arbitrary many occurrences** of the same element in such a way that *exactly a single occurrence* is retained if (and only if) the element occurs at least twice:

```
list_duplicates(Ls, Ds) :-
        phrase(list_duplicates(Ls, []), Ds).

list_duplicates([], _) --> [].
list_duplicates([L|Ls], Ds0) -->
        list_duplicates_(Ls, L, Ds0, Ds),
        list_duplicates(Ls, Ds).

list_duplicates_([], _, Ds, Ds) --> [].
list_duplicates_([L0|Ls], L, Ds0, Ds) -->
        if_(L0=L, new_duplicate(L0, Ds0, Ds1), {Ds0 = Ds1}),
        list_duplicates_(Ls, L, Ds1, Ds).

new_duplicate(E, Ds0, Ds) -->
        new_duplicate_(Ds0, E, Ds0, Ds).

new_duplicate_([], E, Ds0, [E|Ds0]) --> [E].
new_duplicate_([L|Ls], E, Ds0, Ds)  -->
        if_(L=E,
            { Ds0 = Ds },
            new_duplicate_(Ls, E, Ds0, Ds)).
```

The query shown by @fatalize in the comments now yields:

```
?- list_duplicates([a,a,a], Ls).
Ls = [a].
```

The other examples yield the same results. For instance:

```
?- list_duplicates([a,b,c], Ds).
Ds = [].

?- list_duplicates([a,b,a], Ds).
Ds = [a].

?- list_duplicates([a,b,X], Ds).
X = a,
Ds = [a] ;
X = b,
Ds = [b] ;
Ds = [],
dif(X, b),
dif(X, a).

?- list_duplicates([X,Y], Ds).
X = Y,
Ds = [Y] ;
Ds = [],
dif(Y, X).
```

I leave the case `?- list_duplicates(Ls, Ls).` as an exercise.

## Generality: Multiple directions

Ideally, we want to be able to use a relation in **all directions**.

For example, our program should be able to answer questions like:

> What does a list look like *if* its duplicates are `[a,b]`?

With the version shown above, we get:

```
?- list_duplicates(Ls, [a,b]).
nontermination
```

Luckily, a very simple change allows as to *answer* such questions!

One such change is to simply write:

```
list_duplicates(Ls, Ds) :-
        length(Ls, _),
        phrase(list_duplicates(Ls, []), Ds).
```

This is obviously declaratively *admissible*, because `Ls` must be a *list*. *Operationally*, this helps us to enumerate lists in a fair way.

We now get:

```
?- list_duplicates(Ls, [a,b]).
Ls = [a, a, b, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, b, a] ;
Ls = [a, a, a, b, b] ;
Ls = [a, a, b, a, b] ;
Ls = [a, a, b, b, a] ;
Ls = [a, a, b, b, b] ;
Ls = [a, a, b, b, _4632],
dif(_4632, b),
dif(_4632, a) ;
etc.
```

Here is a simpler case, using only a single element:

```
?- list_duplicates(Ls, [a]).
Ls = [a, a] ;
Ls = [a, a, a] ;
Ls = [a, a, _3818],
dif(_3818, a) ;
Ls = [a, _3870, a],
dif(_3870, a) ;
Ls = [_4058, a, a],
dif(a, _4058),
dif(a, _4058) ;
Ls = [a, a, a, a] ;
etc.
```

Maybe even more interesting:

> What does a list **without duplicates** look like?

Our program answers:

```
?- list_duplicates(Ls, []).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [_3240] ;
Ls = [_3758, _3764],
dif(_3764, _3758) ;
Ls = [_4164, _4170, _4176],
dif(_4176, _4164),
dif(_4176, _4170),
dif(_4170, _4164) .
```

Thus, the special case of a list *where all elements are distinct* naturally exists as a **special case** of the more general relation we have implemented.

We can use this relation to **generate** answers (as shown above), and also to **test** *whether* a list consists of distinct elements:

```
?- list_duplicates([a,b,c], []).
true.

?- list_duplicates([b,b], []).
false.
```

Unfortunately, the following even *more general* query still yields:

```
?- list_duplicates([b,b|_], []).
nontermination
```

On the plus side, if the length of the list is *fixed*, we get in such cases:

```
?- length(Ls, L), maplist(=(b), Ls),
   ( true ; list_duplicates(Ls, []) ).
Ls = [],
L = 0 ;
Ls = [],
L = 0 ;
Ls = [b],
L = 1 ;
Ls = [b],
L = 1 ;
Ls = [b, b],
L = 2 ;
Ls = [b, b, b],
L = 3 ;
Ls = [b, b, b, b],
L = 4 .
```

This is some indication that the program indeed **terminates** in such cases. Note that the answers are of course now *too general*.

## Efficiency

It is well known in high-performance computing circles that as long as your program is fast enough, its correctness is barely worth considering.

So, the key question is of course: **How can we make this faster?**

I leave this is a very easy exercise. One way to make this faster in specific cases is to *first* check whether the given list is **sufficiently instantiated**. In that case, you can apply an *ad hoc* solution that fails terribly in more general cases, but has the extreme benefit that it is *fast*!

Comment: @fatalize: Thank you, I have added a version that only retains a single occurrence of the element in such cases.

Comment: If you get blank + `.` at this point, it means *you* have potentially cut away solutions (by pressing `RET` instead of asking for more solutions with `SPACE`). The blank space before the `.` shows that more solutions *may* be available. The program itself *does not terminate* in this case. There is a crucial difference between nontermination and incorrectly omitting solutions. You can always test for universal termination by appending `false` to a query. For example, try: `?- list_duplicates(Ls, [a]), Ls = [_,_,_], false.`. If you add `Ls=[_,_,_]` in front of the query, it terminates.

Comment: True, I wasn't careful there. It still remains that a simple query like `list_duplicates(L,[a,b]).` goes into an infinite loop, and that `list_duplicates(L,[a]).` does not enumerate choice points in an ideal fashion (both problems are most likely linked).

Comment: That is rather easy to fix: Simply add `length(Ls, _)` to `list_duplicates/2`, at an appropriate place.

Comment: @Fatalize: Both your queries contain infinitely many answers as solutions and thus **must not terminate**. Now, insisting that a non-terminating query has to produce answers in a fair manner is desirable, but it is a bit of an unnecessary luxury - since it does not improve termination.

Comment: @false I wouldn't say it's a luxury since e.g. `list_duplicates(L,[a]), L = [a,a,b].` goes into an infinite loop while `L =  [a,a,b], list_duplicates(L,[a]).` works properly. One would at least expect the first one to give an answer once.

Comment: @Fatalize: Your requirements are overarching. You cannot guarantee fair enumeration for any goal - that's what your requirement would be in ultimo fine.

Comment: @Fatalize: I have added more information on how to obtain a version that indeed succeeds once in this case, please have a look.

Comment: @Fatalize: worse, you cannot even realistically expect that termination is maintained! Think of `list_duplicates(_,[X,X|_])` or `list_duplicates(L,[_|L])`

Comment: Hello @mat, thank you for answering. I probably did not explain my problem with the right words. The second argument has to include exactly one occurrence of each element in the first argument that appears more than once.

Comment: @mat Or in other words, each element that occurs more than once in the first argument appears exactly once in the second argument, in the same order as the first occurrences of each item in the first argument. I tried your code but it is correct for the wrongly written question, only elements that occur exactly twice.

Comment: Please try the other versions I posted. They work like you describe and you should be able to use them in your case with at most small adaptations.

Comment: @false Then I don't see why you often preach about correctness of predicates on SO, when the behavior for `list_duplicates(_,[X,X|_])` or `list_duplicates(L,[_|L])` are obviously incorrect but don't seem to bother you.

Comment: @Fatalize: We are using words like "correctness" in quite a different meaning. To me, a definition is correct if, failing goals actually are not true, and (unconditional) succeeding goals are true. But you seem to expect the opposite direction holds as well. That is, practically, quite too demanding. That is: You will rarely ever find such a definition at all. In particular if that definition is itself a pure one. (You always could resort to some constraint-like definition, which however, is much more complex to define - and much more prone to errors.)

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I can tell, you were on the right track with the accumulator, but this implementation definitely works as you want (assuming you want the duplicates in the order they first appear in the list).

`list_duplicates(Input,Output)` is just used to wrap and initialise the accumulator.

`list_duplicates(Accumulator,[],Accumulator)` unifies the accumulator with the output when we have finished processing the input list.

`list_duplicates(Accumulator,[H|T],Output)` says "if the head (`H`) of the input list is in the rest of the list (`T`), and is not in the `Accumulator` already, put it at the end of the `Accumulator` (using `append`), then recurse on the tail of the list".

`list_duplicates(Accumulator,[_|T],Output)` (which we only get to if either the head is not a duplicate, or is already in the `Accumulator`) just recurses on the tail of the list.

```
list_duplicates(Input,Output) :-
    once(list_duplicates([],Input,Output)).

list_duplicates(Accumulator,[],Accumulator).
list_duplicates(Accumulator,[H|T],Output) :-
    member(H,T),
    \+member(H,Accumulator),
    append(Accumulator,[H],NewAccumulator),
    list_duplicates(NewAccumulator,T,Output).
list_duplicates(Accumulator,[_|T],Output) :-
    list_duplicates(Accumulator,T,Output).
```

You could also recurse in `list_duplicates(Accumulator,[H|T],Output)` with `list_duplicates([H|Accumulator],T,Output)` and reverse in the wrapper, looking like this:

```
list_duplicates(Input,Output) :-
    once(list_duplicates([],Input,ReverseOutput)),
    reverse(ReverseOutput,Output).

list_duplicates(Accumulator,[],Accumulator).
list_duplicates(Accumulator,[H|T],Output) :-
    member(H,T),
    \+member(H,Accumulator),
    list_duplicates([H|Accumulator],T,Output).
list_duplicates(Accumulator,[_|T],Output) :-
    list_duplicates(Accumulator,T,Output).
```

The `once` call in the wrapper prevents the `false` output (or in this case, partial duplicate lists due to a lack of guards on the second rule).