# Remove repetitions more than once

Tags: prolog

I would like to remove more than one repetition from a previously ordered list in prolog. I would like the output to look like this:

Example 1.

```
?- remove_dups ([1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6], List).
List = [3,4,6]
```

As you can see, it would remove not a repetition of the same element, but all of it.

I used the following algorithm, I made some modifications but without success.
Here is the algorithm I used:

```
    remove_dups([], []).
    remove_dups([X], [X]).

    remove_dups([X,X|T], [X|R]) :-
        remove_dups([X|T], [X|R]).

    remove_dups([X,Y|T], [X|R]) :-
        X \== Y,
        remove_dups([Y|T], R).

    remove_dups([X,Y|T], [X|R]) :-
        (   X == Y
        ->  remove_dups([Y|T], [X|R])
        ;   remove_dups([Y|T], R)
        ).
```

However the output I have with this algorithm is this.

```
?- remove_dups([1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6], List).

List = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

But I would like it to be as in example 1, any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you detect a duplicate, i.e. unify with `[X,X|T]`, remove the remaining `X`s from the list:

```
remove_dups([], []).
remove_dups([X], [X]).
remove_dups([X,Y|T], [X|R]) :-
    X \= Y,
    remove_dups([Y|T], R).
remove_dups([X,X|T], R) :-
    skip(X, T, WithoutX),
    remove_dups(WithoutX, R).
```

As you can see, you are pretty close: the clauses 1, 2, and 3 of the `remove_dups/2` rule came from your code. The only difference is in the last clause, which skips the remaining values of `X` before recursing down.

The `skip/2` predicate can be implemented as follows:

```
skip(_,[],[]).
skip(X, [X|T], T).
skip(X, [Y|T], [Y|T]) :- X \= Y.
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/h9vOcR)

Comment: In your Skip ([], []), it should be Skip ([], [], []).

Comment: @AndersonMendes Ah, you are right, I was missing the first argument. It should be `_`, not `[]`, though, because it's an item from the list, not an empty list. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a prolog novice. Thank you very much!

Comment: `X=b,remove_dups([a,X],[a,b]).` correctly succeeds, yet `remove_dups([a,X],[a,b]).` fails. Why not try `dif/2`?

Answer (score 3):

This is quite similar to [**Include non-unique elements only**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988973/include-non-unique-elements-only), and can be solved quite analoguously.

I am again using [**`if_//3`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367581/1613573) to retain **generality** of the relation: Please not that a useful Prolog predicate can typically be used in *multiple* directions, and so an imperative name like `remove_dups/2` is not suitable to express other directions and more general use cases.

Instead, I shall call the relation **`list_singulars/2`**, and define it like this:

```
list_singulars(Ls0, Ls) :-
        phrase(list_singulars(Ls0, []), Ls).

list_singulars([], _) --> [].
list_singulars([L|Ls], Ls0) -->
        if_((memberd_t(L, Ls);memberd_t(L, Ls0)),
            [],
            [L]),
        list_singulars(Ls, [L|Ls0]).
```

Here is a simple test case:

```
?- list_singulars([a,a,b], List).
List = [b].
```

And the example you posted:

```
?- list_singulars([1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6], List).
List = [3, 4, 6].
```

Moreover, we can also **generate** answers, using a more *general* query:

```
?- list_singulars([a,X], List).
X = a,
List = [] ;
List = [a, X],
dif(X, a).
```

Note the use of `dif/2`, which is a true relation. See [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) for more information.

Here is the **most general** query:

```
?- list_singulars(Ls0, Ls).
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [_6826] ;
Ls0 = [_6826, _6826],
Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = [_6826, _6826, _6826],
Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = [_6826, _6826, _6826, _6826],
Ls = [] .
```

We can easily obtain **fair enumeration** by *iterative deepening*:

```
?- length(Ls0, _), list_singulars(Ls0, Ls).
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [_7798] ;
Ls0 = [_7798, _7798],
Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = Ls, Ls = [_8436, _8442],
dif(_8442, _8436) ;
Ls0 = [_7798, _7798, _7798],
Ls = [] ;
Ls0 = [_8494, _8494, _8506],
Ls = [_8506],
dif(_8506, _8494) .
```

Comment: Singulars? Not singletons?

Comment: "Singleton" is already occupied by set theory, with a different meaning.

Comment: Please refer to 7.10.3 for the current usage of singletons in the Prolog standard.