# How to find the biggest digit in a number in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have an easy task, but somehow I haven't solved it in over an hour. This recursion I am doing isn't working, I'm stuck in an infinte loop. It should compare the last digit of a number with every other and remember the biggest one. Would really like to know why is my logic faulty and how to solve this problem.

This is my try on it:

```
maxDigit(X,X):-
   X<10.
maxDigit(X,N):-
   X1 is X//10,
   X2 is X mod 10,
   maxDigit(X1,N1),
   X2=<N1,
   N is  N1.
maxDigit(X,N):-
   X1 is X//10,
   X2 is X mod 10,
   maxDigit(X1,N1),
   X2>N1,
   N is X2.
```

Comment: Please add a description in your question body of what you are trying to achive. Question title can be improved as well to something like: "Find biggest digit in a number"

Comment: I fixed your question, but I won't be always your back. Next time follow what @Alex said.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to use if/then/else :

```
maxDigit(X,X):-
   X<10,
   !. % added after false's remark

maxDigit(X,N):-
   X1 is X//10,
   X2 is X mod 10,
   maxDigit(X1,N1),
   (   X2<N1
   ->  N =  N1
   ;   N = X2).
```

Comment: Really elegant. Didn't know about if -> then ; else possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. There is a way to click to accept the solution.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: `maxDigit(0,1).` loops and `maxDigit(0,X)` produces infinitely many (correct but identical) answers.

Comment: @false : yes, this can be solved by a cut after maxDigit(X1,N1).

Comment: That cut is pretty much misplaced - and you have still two answers for `maxDigit(0,X).`

Comment: Maybe it's displaced but I have only one solution for maxDigit(0,X).

Comment: Oups, I'll change my glasses, sorry.

Comment: Hope it's now fixed !

Answer (score 2):

Using SICStus Prolog 4.3.3 we simply combine [`n_base_digits/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801350/4609915) and [`maximum/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Arithmetic-Constraints.html#index-maximum_002f2-_0028clpfd_0029-1) like so:

```
?- n_base_digits(12390238464, 10, _Digits), maximum(Max, _Digits).
Max = 9.
```

Comment: Using `D is 7^7^7 * 10 + 9`, this is *so* slow!

Comment: @false. Actually, it isn't... SICStus is giving me an representation error almost instantly;)

Comment: So you are not using `clpz`.

Answer (score 2):

A comment suggested stopping as soon as the maximum digit is encountered. This is how we do:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).    
:- use_module(library(reif)).

#=(X, Y, T) :- X #= Y #<==> B, bool10_t(B, T).

bool10_t(1, true).
bool10_t(0,false).
```

Based on `if_/3`, `(;)/3` and `(#=)/3` we then define:

```
n_base_maxdigit(N, Base, D) :-
   N    #>  0,                               % positive integers only
   Base #>  1,                               % smallest base = 2
   D    #>= 0,
   D    #<  Base,
   n_base_maxdigit0_maxdigit(N, Base, 0, D).

n_base_maxdigit0_maxdigit(N, Base, D0, D) :-
   D1 #= N mod Base,
   N0 #= N //  Base,
   D2 #= max(D0,D1),
   if_(( D2 + 1 #= Base ; N0 #= 0 ),
       D = D2,
       n_base_maxdigit0_maxdigit(N0, Base, D2, D)).
```

Sample query using SWI-Prolog 7.3.22 with Prolog [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda):

```
?- use_module(library(lambda)).
true.

?- Max+\ ( N is 7^7^7 * 10+9, time(n_base_maxdigit(N,10,Max)) ).
% 663 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (100% CPU, 1022162 Lips)
Max = 9.
```

Comment: In place of `toplevel_print_anon` rather use  λ

Comment: `?- Max+\ ( N is 7^7^7 * 10+9, time(n_base_maxdigit(N,10,Max)) ).`

Answer (score 0):

in SWI-Prolog could be:

```
maxDigit(N,M) :- number_codes(N,L), max_list(L,T), M is T-0'0.
```

Comment: Alright! How about using `max_member(T,L)` instead of `max_list(L,T)` and adding `:- use_module(library(lists)).` ? That way the same code would run with SWI *and* SICStus.